# How to refer to the number of an item in an enumerate environment inside a theorem

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, amsmath, theorems, enumerate

I have something that looks like this:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
The following are true:
\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{foo} Foo
\item \label{bar} Bar
\item \label{baz} Baz
\end{enumerate}
\end{thm}

Refer to Theorem \ref{bar}

\end{document}
```

Right now, the reference to bar shows up as Theorem 1. I want it to show up as Theorem 1.2. Is there any way to do that? To give a sub-numbering to each label within a theorem?

Comment: That numbering scheme is likely to confuse your readers...

Comment: Fair enough, I'm fine with the 1 (2) scheme egreg gives.

Comment: i think the question would be more obvious with a slight change of title: "How to refer to the number of an item in an enumerate ..."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I agree with Jubobs comment: using "Theorem 1.2" is very likely to be confusing.

Here's how one might do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{thmenum}
 {\begin{enumerate}[label=\upshape(\arabic*),ref=\thethm(\arabic*)]}
 {\end{enumerate}}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
The following are true:
\begin{thmenum}
\item \label{foo} Foo
\item \label{bar} Bar
\item \label{baz} Baz
\end{thmenum}
\end{thm}

Refer to Theorem \ref{bar}

\end{document}
```

I'd give the items a distinctive numbering, so that it will be clearer that "Theorem 1(2)" refers to statement 2 in theorem 1.

[image]

##### Edit for feature request

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\NewDocumentCommand{\refprefix}{m}{%
  \ifinproofref\else #1\fi
 }
\newif\ifinproofref
\newcommand{\proofref}[1]{\begingroup\inproofreftrue\ref{#1}\endgroup}

\newenvironment{thmenum}
 {\begin{enumerate}[label=\upshape(\arabic*),ref=\refprefix{\thethm}(\arabic*)]}
 {\end{enumerate}}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
The following are true:
\begin{thmenum}
\item \label{foo} Foo
\item \label{bar} Bar
\item \label{baz} Baz
\end{thmenum}
\end{thm}
\begin{proof}
\proofref{foo} is easy. \proofref{bar} is not difficult and 
immediately proves also~\proofref{baz}.
\end{proof}

Refer to Theorem~\ref{bar}

\end{document}
```

The format of the `ref` is made so `\thethm` can be omitted. You have to use `\proofref` when referring to the item.

[image]

Comment: I know that this is an old answer, but luckily you're still around: how can I `\ref` to the items in the proof (but only there!) by *(1)* instead of *1(2)*?

Comment: @Bubaya Added a solution.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe that leads too far, but why doesn't `\newcommand{\refprefix}{...}` work?

Comment: @Bubaya I used `\NewDocumentCommand` on purpose, because with `\newcommand` it wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. Please see my separate question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/679839/27717