# Difference between `\newcommand{..}[1]` and `\NewDocumentCommand{..}{m}`

Tags: macros, auxiliary-files, latex-base

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/115804/27717), egreg uses

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\refprefix}{m}{%
  \ifinproofref\else #1\fi
}
```

The command `\refprefix` is part of code that's written to the aux file. Defining the command with

```
\newcommand{\refprefix}[1]{%
  \ifinproofref\else #1\fi
}
```

does not work, apparently, because `\refprefix` is already expanded on writing the aux file.

Why is that so, and which other definition-like commands behave in what way in this context?

Comment: Related (or even a duplicate): [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands? When and why do we need \protect?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/277964)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in this context is that `\NewDocumentCommand` uses e-tex `\protected\def` so the command does not expand in a `\write`. You could use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` to define an unprotected version.  Similarly in classic latex, you could use `\DeclareRobustCommand` to define a command that does not expand (using LaTeX  `\protect` mechanism rather than `\protected`).